# Eclipse NEON Oralce ADF Essentials not showing in pallete

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2.2, oracle-adf

I tried to create an **ADF Application** using Eclipse NEON

I am able to create an **ADF Page**, but the **Palette** is not showing **ADF Faces** components

The eclipse is not providing auto completion for `<af:` code

Comment: Please refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302844/oracle-adf-with-glassfish-4-error-while-running-the-jspx/41311543#41311543

Comment: Ok I will look into it