# Oracle ADF with GlassFish 4 error while running the JSPX

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, oracle-adf

I have followed [Oracle Enterprise Pack Eclipse ADF](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/eclipse/adf/gettingStarted/Tutorial/ADFwithOEPE_3.html) but I used GlassFish instead of weblogic.

When Tried to execute http://localhost:18080/HRWeb/faces/MainHR.jspx I am getting the following exception

```
2016-12-23T19:45:21.545+0530|Info: jndi:/server/HRWeb/WEB-INF/classes/view/DataBindings.cpx
2016-12-23T19:45:25.249+0530|Info: Added skin addition org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.skin.SkinAddition@1910271752 {styleSheetName: META-INF/adf/styles/fusion-base-theme-addition.css} to skin org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.skin.SkinExtension@521539624 {id: fusion-base.desktop, version: , styleSheetName: META-INF/adf/styles/fusion-base-desktop.css, bundleName: oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.resource.RichBundle, extends: [simple.desktop]}
2016-12-23T19:45:25.250+0530|Info: Added skin addition org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.skin.SkinAddition@2037844104 {styleSheetName: META-INF/adf/styles/fusion-theme-addition.css} to skin org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.skin.SkinExtension@2017400613 {id: fusion.desktop, version: , styleSheetName: META-INF/adf/styles/fusion-desktop.css, bundleName: oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.resource.RichBundle, extends: [fusion-base.desktop, simple.desktop]}
2016-12-23T19:45:25.394+0530|Warning: ADF_FACES-60098:Faces lifecycle receives unhandled exceptions in phase RENDER_RESPONSE 6
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CAP_ACTIVE_DATA_CHANNEL_SHARING
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.SessionDataUpdateManager.<init>(SessionDataUpdateManager.java:92)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.RichDataUpdateManagerFactory._getSessionDataUpdateManager(RichDataUpdateManagerFactory.java:157)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.RichDataUpdateManagerFactory.getDataUpdateManager(RichDataUpdateManagerFactory.java:91)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.context.AdfFacesContextImpl.getDataUpdateManager(AdfFacesContextImpl.java:166)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.activedata.ActiveComponentContext.<init>(ActiveComponentContext.java:81)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.activedata.ActiveComponentContext.getActiveComponentContext(ActiveComponentContext.java:99)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.context.RichRequestContextImpl.pushCurrentComponent(RichRequestContextImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:1217)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.component.AdfViewRoot.encodeAll(AdfViewRoot.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.doRenderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:431)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:232)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:101)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl$ChangeApplyingVDLWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:338)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:170)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.ResponseRenderManager.runRenderView(ResponseRenderManager.java:52)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:1264)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeRenderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:1107)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:348)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:258)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using HR Schema from Oracle Express Edition 11g

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this Official Oracle URL [Configuring and Using ADF with GlassFish Server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/downloads/index.html)

It says

> Download the Oracle ADF Essentials file **adf-essentials.zip** to a temporary location. You will install the ADF Runtime library files into the GlassFish installation directory, as described in Section 3.10.3, "How to Configure GlassFish for OEPE."
>
> Download the Oracle ADF Essentials Client files **adf-essentials-client-ear.zip** and **adf-essentials-client-war.zip** to a temporary location and then extract the files to flat-structured temporary directories, a separate directory for each download.

Which means you have to download three files

1. adf-essentials.zip -- needs to be installed in server
2. adf-essentials-client-ear.zip -- needs to go with EAR project
3. adf-essentials-client-war.zip -- needs to go with WAR project

You might also need to download [easybeans-persistence-eclipselink-2.4.x-1.0.1.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/easybeans/persistence/easybeans-persistence-eclipselink-2.4.x/1.0.1/easybeans-persistence-eclipselink-2.4.x-1.0.1.jar) and put it inside the glassfish domain lib folder where you have placed the adf essentials

If you follow this procedure properly then your issue will be resolved.

Note: There could be many exceptions thrown in the server log, but your application will work as expected also your screen will render as specified in that tutorial.